# Listando y guardando Modelos anidados Angular 9

Tags: sql-server, angular, json, api, .net-core

Anteriormente había posteado una pregunta, pero sin la información necesaría, así que aquí voy de nuevo:

Tengo una API en .net core 3.1 que me devuelve una lista de productos con su categoría correspondiente en Json:

```
{
"IdProducto": 3,
"NombreProducto": "Pocky",
"Descripcion": "Barquillos cubiertos de chocolate",
"Precio": 15000,
"Cantidad": 10,
"FechaVencimiento": "2020-06-30T00:00:00",
"RutaFotoProducto": "774484",
"TablaNutricion": "77938475",
"FkidCategoria": 3,
"FkidEstadoProducto": 1,
"FkidCategoriaNavigation": {
    "IdCategoria": 3,
    "NombreCategoria": "Chocolates",
    "DescripcionCategoria": "Productos a cubiertos de chocolate",
    "Producto": []
},
"FkidEstadoProductoNavigation": null,
"DetalleCompraProducto": [],
"DetallePedidoProducto": []
```

}

Tengo mi interfaz de Categoria

```
export interface Categoria {
  IdCategoria: number;
  NombreCategoria: string;
  DescripcionCategoria: string;
}
```

Y mi interfaz de Producto

```
import { Categoria } from './categoria.model';

export interface Producto {
  IdProducto: number;
  NombreProducto: String;
  Descripcion: String;
  Precio: number;
  Cantidad: number;
  FechaVencimiento: Date;
  RutaFotoProducto: String;
  TablaNutricion: String;
  FkidCategoria:number;
  FkidEstadoProducto: number;
  categoria?:Categoria;
}
```

Aquí es dónde empiezo a tener problemas, ya que he visto varios vídeos y veo que en lugar de la clave foránea "FkidCategoria" que creó el EF Core con Database First, crean un objeto en este caso categoria e importan el modelo Categoria. Ya que no comprendo en dónde establecería para devolver hacia la base de datos el campo "FkidCategoria" dentro de la tabla "Producto".

Además tengo un servicio que se encarga del CRUD de Productos y en este tengo instanciado el FormBuilder de la siguiente manera:

```
    export class GestionProductoService {

    formRegistroProducto = this.formBuilder.group({
    IdProducto: [0],
    NombreProducto:["",[Validators.required]],
    Descripcion:[""],
    Precio:["",[Validators.required]],
    Cantidad:["",[Validators.required]],
    FechaVencimiento:[""],
    RutaFotoProducto:[""],
    TablaNutricion: [""],
    FkidCategoria:[""],
    FkidEstadoProducto:["",[Validators.required]],
    });

  producto:Producto;
  listaProducto:Producto[];

  get NombreProducto(){
    return this.formRegistroProducto.controls["NombreProducto"];
  }
  get Descripcion(){
    return this.formRegistroProducto.controls["Descripcion"];
  }  get Precio(){
    return this.formRegistroProducto.controls["Precio"];
  }  get Cantidad(){
    return this.formRegistroProducto.controls["Cantidad"];
  }  get FechaVencimiento(){
    return this.formRegistroProducto.controls["FechaVencimiento"];
  }  get RutaFotoProducto(){
    return this.formRegistroProducto.controls["RutaFotoProducto"];
  }  get TablaNutricion(){
    return this.formRegistroProducto.controls["TablaNutricion"];
  }  get FkidCategoria(){
    return this.formRegistroProducto.controls["FkidCategoria"];
  }  get FkidEstadoProducto(){
    return this.formRegistroProducto.controls["FkidEstadoProducto"];
  }
  constructor(private http:HttpClient, private configuracion:ConfiguracionService, private formBuilder:FormBuilder) {}
```

pero no tengo ni idea igualmente como implementaría el modelo categoría

y por último en mi componente para listar los productos he tratado de que al llenar la tabla, la columna de categoría me muestre el nombre de la categoría en lugar del IdCategoria:

```
<div class="container">
<table class="table-responsive">
<thead class="table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
      <th scope="col">Descripción</th>
      <th scope="col">Precio</th>
      <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
      <th scope="col">Fecha <br> vencimiento</th>
      <th scope="col">Foto</th>
      <th scope="col">Información Nutricional</th>
      <th scope="col">Categoria</th>
      <th scope="col">Estado</th>
      <th scope="col">Eliminar</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let producto of gestionProductoService.listaProducto">
      <td (click)="llenarFormularioProducto(producto)">{{producto.NombreProducto}}</td>
      <td (click)="llenarFormularioProducto(producto)">{{producto.Descripcion}}</td>
      <td (click)="llenarFormularioProducto(producto)">{{producto.Precio}}</td>
      <td (click)="llenarFormularioProducto(producto)">{{producto.Cantidad}}</td>
      <td (click)="llenarFormularioProducto(producto)">{{producto.FechaVencimiento}}</td>
      <td (click)="llenarFormularioProducto(producto)">{{producto.RutaFotoProducto}}</td>
      <td (click)="llenarFormularioProducto(producto)">{{producto.TablaNutricion}}</td>
      <td (click)="llenarFormularioProducto(producto)">{{producto.FkidCategoria}}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let categoria of producto.categoria">{{categoria.IdCategoria}}</td>
      <!-- <tr *ngFor="let categoria of gestionCategoriaService.listaCategoria"> -->
      <!-- <td (click)="llenarFormularioProducto(categoria)">{{categoria.NombreCategoria}}</td> -->
      <td (click)="llenarFormularioProducto(producto)">{{producto.FkidEstadoProducto}}</td>
      <td><i (click)="eliminarProducto(producto.IdProducto)" class="fa fa-trash-o center fa-2x text-danger"></i>
      </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

pero ya que tengo un método que al hacer clic en una de las filas de la tabla me envía los datos del indice seleccionado a los campos de form, y en estos es necesario el IdCategoria y no el nombre, no me funciona, y no sé si para mostrar el nombre de la categoria debería usar un pipe o algo así {{categoria.NombreCategoria}}

Código del método llenarFormularioRegistro producto:

```
  llenarFormularioProducto(producto:Producto){
    this.gestionProductoService.formRegistroProducto.patchValue(producto);
  }
```

Anexo una captura de la vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola no me queda claro cual es su pregunta pero me gustaria poder ayudarle.

Comment: Buenas tardes, eso supuse, demasiada información, siempre me sucede, la primera pregunta sería:
Cómo se implementa el modelo anidado, porque yo lo creo "categoria?:Categoria", pero no entiendo cómo haría para guardar mi producto, si mi controlador Producto en la API espera un atributo FkidCategoria(es la clave foranea que conecta con la tabla de categoria)

Comment: Eso lo puede lograr teniendo un modelo para leer(presentar ) los datos y otro para el Post donde solo pasa la llave de la categoria.

Comment: Es decir que debería crear dos interfaces separadas de productos en angular, uno donde anide la interfaz de categoría, y la otra solo tenga el atributo de llave foránea? pero eso no sería algo redundante?y por ejemplo a la hora de llenar la tabla debería usar ambos modelos? ya que con uno llenaría la columna  Categoria con el nombre de la categoria y al hacer clic en alguna de las filas el me debería enviar el Id de la categoria al formulario de Registro producto, es correcto?

Comment: Las respuestas para un programador no son absolutas y siempre hay formas de mejorar una solucion. Mi recomendacion es para que tenga la funcionalidad lista, otra solucion es usar GraphQL (https://graphql.org/) pero es algo mas complicado. Vamos a tomar un ejemplo y vamos a desarrollarlo completamente para que usted tenga un ejemplo.

Comment: Entiendo, gracias por el aporte probaré que tal funciona